# Distance in k-NN

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

In the K-nearest-neighbors model, we use 
\begin{equation}
\hat{f}(x)=Ave(y_i \mid x_i \in N_k(x))
\end{equation}
where $N_k(x)$ is a neighborhood of a certain size of x. 
What is the actual distance that we use to determine the neighborhood of x? At first i thought that it was $d((x_i,y_i),(x,y))=\sqrt{(x_i-x)^2+(y_i -y)^2}$ but that's not the case. The distance used (i think) is $d(x_0,x)=\left|x_0 - x \right|$. It seems to me that using the first distance is more intuitive, but then it's not the one that is used. Why?

Thanks

Comment: But if $ \vec x_0 := (x_i, y_i)$ and $\vec x := (x, y)$, then $| \vec x_0 -\vec x| = \sqrt{(x_i - x)^2 + (y_i - y)^2}$.

Comment: but here $x_0$ is the x-coordinate not the vector.

Comment: So your distance metric ignores the $y$-coordinates???

Comment: Also, i've implemented knn on python using these two distances, and the latter one gives much better results

Comment: yes that's what i mean.

Comment: Did you scale your coordinates so that they are of comparable scale? (For example, if your datapoints are people, and if $x$ is height and $y$ is weight, then you don't want to measure height in kilometres and weight in milligrams.)

Comment: yes, they are of comparable scale i just implemented it using noisy data $Y=\cos(X)+\epsilon$, and $X\in(-1,1)$.

Comment: ...yjint So $x$ and $y$ are both inputs? Then what is the _target_ variable?

Comment: The target variable is Y. I 'm trying to predict Y given X values. A little precision i forgot to mention: the $X$'s are 100 points equally seperated in $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Well in that case, it doesn't make sense to use $y$ as a part of the distance metric! Your distance metric should only be computed from _input_ variables. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to predict anything with your model!

Comment: Sorry but i don't get it. Here the "training set" are the X and Y's that i use initially. I'm trying to fit a curve using these datas so i can then predict Y for a certain X in $(-1,1)$. Why wouldn't i be able to predict with my model?

Comment: Because for a test point, you don't know the $y$! So if your distance metric uses $y$'s, then you won't be able to calculate the distance between your test point and the various training points.

Comment: Obviously. It's clear now, i didn't pay attention to this detail. Thank's a lot